# Compound Poisson processes. Interestnig properties

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I'm currently finishing my bachleor's studies and have to pick a topic for my bachelor's thesis. I'm leaning towards analysing the compound Poisson process, but since the thesis should be about 30 pages I don't thing only proving basic results will suffice. What would be an interesting property of the process I could study in my thesis? Possibly something to do with finance, and if you give any suggestions I would appreciate a refference to the material that covers said suggested topic.

Comment: The mother of all finance papers dealing with the first jump of a compound Poisson process (the author says Cox process) is: D. Lando, *On Cox Processes and Credit Risky Securities* (1998). You should be able to find a free pdf of this in the internet. Even if you re-write that in a more introductory style and  fill in the steps in the proofs that Lando skipped for brevity it would not surprise me if that bachelor thesis becomes way longer than 30 pages. So my advice is to read it first before making a decision.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but after skimming through the paper, the material seem a bit out of my current knowledge of stochastic processes. Is there perhaps some other topic I could tackle?